# Float numbers weird after division

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

I'm having a little trouble undestanding one thing on python.
I was trying to pick the rest of a division on a floating number, but i think i run into an error, because the result keeping coming wrong.

As an example, if I write this:

```
a = 2.9%2
b = 2.4%2
c = 2.1%2

print('{}\n{}\n{}'.format(a, b, c))
```

it returns

```
0.8999999999999999
0.3999999999999999
0.10000000000000009
```

Comment: @KenWhite: Python's modulo op _is_ for floating point as well, and it's very convenient.

Comment: @DSM: I knew I should have just stayed with the dupe link. Thanks. (Not sure I agree about *very convenient*, as FP modulo would seem to be pretty futile, but I stand corrected about it not existing.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't found this post